# why always structured Images are considered as 2D signals?

Tags: image-processing

I am dealing with 2D signals that are random. To be more specific my input is a matrix of 1's and 0's. Moreover, at any position (n1,n2) the probability of having a 1 or a 0 is same. One example is shown below

[image]

When I look at books dealing with 2D signal processing, everything is explained wrt to image processing. In my understanding, image is a very special kind of 2D signal where one can expect to see some relationship between the pixels like EDGES. Such features are useful when doing image restoration,etc.

[image]

These books start with defining 2D signals and system but explain everything wrt to image processing application which is a bit restrictive. 
Why is the case?

Comment: Your question seems almost rhetorical.  You have two reasonable answers. Are you expecting something more?  Image processing deal with most situations you would find in 2D signal processing --- even without edges. Can you elaborate on your particular problem so we can show you what sort of image processing techniques might be applicable to it?  You seem to have a very limited view of image processing.

Answer (score 1):

A 1D signal that is only noise with no structured feature to be seen is of no interest.

A 2D signal that is only noise or a superposition of uncorrelated 1D signal rows, with no 2D structured feature to be seen, is of no interest.

Comment: There are applications in framework of communication theory where such signals are of interest.

Answer (score 0):

A grayscale image is typically a 2D scalar valued signal, while a colour image is a 2D vector valued signal. It doesn't have to be structured, I would call your example a noise image. Most images are of real-life objects, and so naturally contain some structure.

The purpose of image analysis is to extract information from an image. Most of that information is contained within image features such as lines or edges. Random noisy images contain very little information and are not really of interest. Hence why textbooks don't feature them.

One kind of 2D signal without structure but which is of great interest is the Fourier transform of an image. These typically have few lines or edges.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do agree with your comment that"Noisy images" are of little interest but would like to add that they do show up in high density storage applications. Its a communication theory problem. Since image processing (IP) deals with "nice images", results from IP cannot be applied to this new application :(